# Javascript regex to match type annotations

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match type annotations from a string of parameters:

```
foo: string, bar:number, baz: Array<string>
```

my initial pattern was working fine for primitives:

```
:\s*\w+
```

but it's not capturing arrays, so I tried an alternation, but it's not working:

```
:\s*\w+|:\s*\w+<\w+>
```

end result should be:

```
foo, bar, baz
```

Comment: Pehaps like this `(\w+):\s*\w` https://regex101.com/r/ev92kV/1

Comment: `s.match(/\w+(?=:\s*\w)/g)` or `s.match(/\w+(?=:\s*\w)/g).join(", ")` - https://regex101.com/r/tVifKe/1

Comment: Or remove them `:\s*\w+(?:<\w+>)?` https://regex101.com/r/lpEYXL/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the part with the brackets optional and replace the matches with an empty string leaving the desired result:

```
:\s*\w+(?:<\w+>)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NTn5No/1)

```js
let s = "foo: string, bar:number, baz: Array<string>";
console.log(s.replace(/:\s*\w+(?:<\w+>)?/g, ''));
```

Or match the parts using a capturing group

```
(\w+):\s*\w
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lpEYXL/1/)

```js
let s = "foo: string, bar:number, baz: Array<string>";
let matches = Array.from(s.matchAll(/(\w+):\s*\w/g), m => m[1]);
console.log(matches.join(", "));
```